# Prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i\geq n^2$.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, conjectures

A hint can be helpful, but not a whole solution.

**The Problem (conjecture):**

> Given a natural number $n \geq 1$ and a sequence of natural numbers $(a_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ in which for every pair $(i,j)$ with $i \neq j,$ we have 
>   $$\gcd(a_i,a_j)\nmid i-j$$
>   prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i\geq n^2$.

**What I have done:**

> During my research, I ran into this problem and I am not quite sure if it is true. It is clear if we put **$a_i=n$** then the problem will be solved and the summation will be equal to $n^2$. 
>   I tried to solve this problem.
>
> For example, I showed that $$a_i> max(i,n-i)$$ otherwise, I can put $j=i+a_i$ or $j=i-a_i$ and considering the fact $\gcd(a_i,a_j) \mid a_i,$ then we conclude that 
>   $\gcd(a_i,a_j)\mid i-j,$
>   hence, $a_i> max(i,n-i)$ which means that $a_i\geq \dfrac{n} {2}$.
>
> Moreover,  if $a_i\leq n$ and p are prime divisors of $a_i$ by putting $j=i-\dfrac {a_i}{p}$ for $i\geq \dfrac {n} {2}$ and $j=i+\dfrac {a_i}{p}$ for $i\leq \dfrac {n} {2}$ we could conclude that $a_i \mid a_j$.
>
> I could go further, but it is not enough to prove the conjecture. I also tried Induction and considered that the property holds for every $n\leq k$ and then try to prove the theorem for $n= k+1$ but again, there are some issues that I could not go further.

Comment: What is this mod function?

Comment: @Ovi $\mod(a,b)$ stands for the residue of $a$ modulo $b$. It is common in math softwares. Hence,  $\mod(a,b)>0$ is equivalent to $b\not\mid a$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Ah got it thanks

Comment: How far have you been looking for a counterexample? How far do you know this to be true?

Comment: I edited the problem notation, so it is clearer now. I have tried for n=2,3,4,5,6. Then I stopped and guessed it might be true. I coded the problem with an optimisation software GAMS to find the minimum value of summation of a(i)  for all the numbers lower than 100, however I am not done yet!

Comment: So you want to prove the conjecture for every $n$?

Comment: Yes this conjecture is for every natural $n\geq 2$.

Comment: @farshidevazabadian Can $a_i$ depend on $n$?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to find the minimum possible value for summation of $a_i$, hence, it dpeneds on $n$.Moreover since I have shown that $a_i\geq n-i$, so, the value of $a_i$ could not be fixed for all the $n$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier My program verified this conjecture for $n\leqslant28$ (It takes unbearably long time to run the program for $n\geqslant26$).

Comment: With natural numbers, do you mean integers $\geq 1$ or is $0$ included?

Answer (score 7):

Your conjecture is true.

If you want only a hint, stop reading after recalling that $\gcd(a_i,a_j) \mid i-j$ is equivalent to the solvability of the system of congruences
$$ \left\{ \begin{align*} x \equiv i \pmod {a_i} \\
x \equiv j \pmod {a_j}\end{align*}\right.$$

---

By the Chinese remainder theorem, we can formulate the problem equivalently as follows: consider $n$ arithmetic progressions in $\mathbb Z$, $(S_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ with $i \in S_i$ for all $i$ and with differences $a_i$. That is, $S_i = i + a_i \mathbb Z$. If the $S_i$ are pairwise disjoint, prove that $\sum a_i \geq n^2$.

The conclusion remains true even without the hypothesis that $i \in S_i$:

If the $S_i$ are disjoint, they are also disjoint mod $a_1 \cdots a_n$, and hence
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\# (S_i \bmod a_1 \cdots a_n) & \leq a_1 \cdots a_n \\
\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j \neq i} a_j &\leq \prod_{i=1}^n a_i \end{align*}$$
divide by the RHS to obtain
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{a_i} \leq 1$$
And by [AM-HM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-HM)
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \geq n^2$$

Also from AM-HM we have that equality occurs iff $a_1 = \cdots = a_n = n$.

Comment: +1 very elegant.

Comment: Wonderful! I'm not sure though that the reference to CRT is needed. Also I think you may hide some parts of your answer under the [**spoiler tag**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers), as OP asked not to post a complete solution.

Comment: @zhoraster Right, I forgot that the OP only wanted a hint. I don't like spoiler tags for long solutions, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas: if $a_n \geq 2n - 1$, you can proceed by induction. Hence you may assume that $n \leq a_n \leq 2n - 1$. In this case your second observation becomes quite a bit stronger. Indeed, for any prime $p$ dividing $a_n$ we may take $i = n$ and $j = n - \frac{a_n}{p}$. Note that $1 \leq j < n$ exactly by our condition $n \leq a_n \leq 2n - 1$.